# Chrome declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules - response headers modification breaks other not related webapps

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, response-headers

I'm trying to add a response header to some requests using my chrome extension. While it works as expected for the website I'm trying to deal with, it breaks some other web applications not even specified in the manifest. I noticed, those apps are using SSO authentication and it breaks them while it loads the page.

One of the examples:
During initial load a webapp (ASP.NET dashboard) is loading some resources (page itself, scripts, some json file) and then it's making an API call to https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track. I compared all calls up until this one - all look the same, and this is the first one that fails if I have my extension installed.
If I remove the extension - everything works fine, app is loading and showing the dashboard.
I also noticed that this API call is not exactly the same as the one from working scenario (without extension installed). It's missing a lot of headers (7 vs 21), and it's not even showing if it's a preflight or actual POST request.

I spent a lot of time trying to debug and see what's wrong, but no luck so far.

Here is my config

manifest.json

```json
{
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "notifications",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "cookies",
    "scripting",
    "declarativeNetRequest"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://somedomain.com/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
...
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
  removeRuleIds: [123456],
  addRules: [{
    id: 123456,
    priority: 1,
    condition: {
      regexFilter: 'https://somedomain.com', // tried urlFilter too
      domains: ['somedomain.com'],
      resourceTypes: [
        chrome.declarativeNetRequest.ResourceType.MAIN_FRAME
      ]
    },
    action: {
      type: chrome.declarativeNetRequest.RuleActionType.MODIFY_HEADERS,
      responseHeaders: [
        {
          header: 'foo',
          operation: chrome.declarativeNetRequest.HeaderOperation.SET,
          value: 'bar'
        }
      ]
    }
  }]
})
```

As you see - I'm setting a custom header here (just for an example). Real intention is to modify `Content-Security-Policy` header. No matter what header I'm touching or adding - the result is always the same.
If I provide an empty array in `responseHeaders` setting in background.js - everything works. It starts failing if there is an entry in that array.

`chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getDynamicRules()` returns only the rule I've created - no other rules.

I also tried to add a similar static rule to manifest.json. It gives the same result.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: This code is fine, so maybe there's a bug in Chrome. Try uninstalling the extension and installing it again. Note that devtools may show incorrect headers in this case, so use an external tool like Fiddler, Charles, WireShark.

Comment: Yes, I installed-uninstalled the extension many many times for debugging. Thanks for the idea of using different tools for looking into headers. The problem is that my company is restricting usage of external plugins :(

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/1468558

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm for a right direction. This is indeed a bug in Chromium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @wOxxOm for a right direction.
This is indeed a bug in Chromium - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1468558

I've used one of the suggestions from the bug page and added a workaround to my code, which worked well.

The workaround was to add a dummy listener to background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  () => {},
  { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
  ['requestHeaders', 'extraHeaders'],
);
```

I also had to modify host_permissions in manifest.json like this:

```
"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
```